# Assigning icon to Cocoa app -- possible to use SVG?

Tags: cocoa, macos, icons, svg, png

I was wondering how to use an image I created as an icon. I put the filename into my plist file, and named the icon "icon.png", and dragged it in, and it is still not working.

Also, is there any way to use an SVG file as the icon for a Cocoa app?

Comment: SVG is not a possible icon format in Mac OS X. PDF can be used for in-app icons and icns must be used for the application's icon which shows up in Finder and the Dock.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to convert the `png`s (1024px, 512px, 256px, 128px, 32px and 16px) to an `icns` using Icon Composer which can be found in `/Developer/Applications/Utilities/`. It works using drag & drop.

Then just import the icns into the app and add the name of it (without `.icns`) into `Info.plist`.